# Paste a table from Excel into Word then transform it

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am beginner at coding with VBA. So, although the following code works very well, I am looking for a way to optimize and reduce it.

Its objective is to:

1- paste a table from Excel into Word without losing Excel format

2- process the pasted table

3- move out of the table, then add new line/empty paragraph

```
Sub TablePasteAndTransform()    
    
    With Selection

        ' paste from excel at the cursor position
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        .PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
        .MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        If Not .Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            MsgBox "Can only run this within a table"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        With .Tables(1)
            ' process the pasted table
            .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)            
            .Cell(1, 1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
            .Cell(1, 1).PreferredWidth = 75
            .Select
        End With

        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd        
        .Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
        .MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph
        
    End With

    ThisDocument.Save
    
End Sub
```

Comment: So it works, it's just slower than you would like?

Comment: @braX It is pretty fast actually, but I am looking for a more experienced way to do the job instead of my beginner approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub TablePasteAndFormat()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
  With Selection
    .Collapse (wdCollapseStart)
    With .Range
      .PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
      'or
      ' .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
      With .Tables(1)
        .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
        .Cell(1, 1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
        .Cell(1, 1).PreferredWidth = 75
        .Range.Characters.Last.Next.InsertBefore vbCrLf
      End With
      .Start = .Tables(1).Range.End + 1
      .Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
      .Select
    End With
  End With
  .Save
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: That's pretty elegant. Unknowingly, `.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting` makes the pasted table look better without the unwanted spaces at the bottom of each cell.

Comment: You can replace *.PasteExcelTable False, False, False* with *.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting* if that gives a better result. Alternatively or additionally, you could modify the paragraph before/after and/or line spacing used in the table.