# Copy multiple tables from selected Excel ranges to Word under each other

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The following is an Excel VBA code that aims to copy the selected excel range and paste it into a Word document at the very next paragraph below the current cursor position.

However, there are issues with the code:

1- How to use the word document I set by `Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents("Test.docx")` so that I can avoid pasting into another document by mistake?

2- Why do both instances of `MoveDown` fail when explicitly setting their options to `Unit:=wdparagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove`, and get the error

> Run-time error '4120': Bad parameter

```
Sub CopyTableToWord()

Selection.Copy

Dim WordApp As Object
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True

Dim WordDoc As Object
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents("Test.docx")

' cursor position
WordApp.Selection.Range.Characters.Last.InsertParagraphAfter
WordApp.Selection.MoveDown 'Unit:=wdparagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove

With WordApp.Selection

  .Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
  
  With .Range.Tables(1)
    
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
    .AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
    .Range.Select
    
  End With

    ' move out of the table, then add space after it 
    ' to move the Word cursor to the new position
    ' of the next table to be pasted
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    .MoveDown 'Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It's pointless setting a reference to WordDoc, then using WordApp.Selection when WordApp.Selection might not be pointing to the same document. You also need to tell us how the code is to identify the Excel ranges to copy, especially since you say there are multiple tables. And, instead of relying on Selection, how the program might identify the Word range(s) to past at (e.g. one or more bookmarks).

Comment: @macropod Generally speaking, I need to select some range from the Excel file, then the code has to copy/paste it into the specific Word file. After pasting and processing the pasted table, I need to add some vertical space (separating the successive tables), then move the cursor below to get ready for the next copy/paste.

Comment: If you know the Excel ranges to copy, there is no need to go through all that circumlocution. In any event, copying/pasting one-at-a-time makes the Word automation much more complicated, since it has to find the last Word instance in which the paste was done each time rather than starting a new one.

Comment: I've updated the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925700/paste-a-table-from-excel-into-word-then-transform-it to re-position the insertion point so the next table copied can be pasted without having to manually re-select anything.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Out of curiosity, regarding my second question, why do both instances of `MoveDown` fail when explicitly setting their options? Also, for my self-learning, it would be great if you could propose an answer here even though it is not the best solution to the problem since OneDrive doesn't provide autosave option for macro-enabled Word documents `*.docm` unlike Excel counterparts `*.xlsm`.

Comment: Your Movedown attempts are most likely failing because you're using named Word constants, but you're using late binding. When using late binding, you need to either declare those constants and assign the relevant Word enumeration to them or use the corresponding enumeration directly, as per my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For copying & pasting tables one at a time and with only a single instance of Word running, you could use something like:

```
Sub PasteAndFormatTableInWord()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Const StrDocNm As String = "Test.docx"
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wdApp Is Nothing Then Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
With wdApp
  'Check if the document is open.
  For Each wdDoc In .Documents
    If wdDoc.Name = StrDocNm Then Exit For
  Next
  If wdDoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Your '" & StrDocNm & "' document isn't open." & vbCr & _
      "Please open the document and select the insertion point.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
  End If
  wdDoc.Activate
  With .Selection
    .Collapse 1 'wdCollapseStart
    With .Range
      .PasteAndFormat 16 'wdFormatOriginalFormatting
      With .Tables(1)
        .AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
        .Cell(1, 1).PreferredWidthType = 3 'wdPreferredWidthPoints
        .Cell(1, 1).PreferredWidth = 75
        .Range.Characters.Last.Next.InsertBefore vbCrLf
      End With
      .Start = .Tables(1).Range.End + 1
      .Collapse 0 'wdCollapseEnd
      .Select
    End With
  End With
  wdDoc.Save
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```